# How to refetch all query when come back to home page using apollo client

Tags: apollo, next.js

I'm using appollo client and nextjs, when i use next/link to go back to home page (client side), all data of my homepage still old and doesn't update to new data (I think it used cache data). Only if i refresh page use F5 (server side), it's updated. So how to update data in client side, thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Apollo client you can specify **fetchPolicy: network-only** to always get updated data without refreshing the page

There is one more option provided by Apollo is **refechQueries** you can use this also.